# Get hashed filename in Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have Webpack configured to copy files with the hash in the filename for cache busting:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
    loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
  },
```

The result is that a filename like **img.png** gets turned into **img.3423543534234325346436.png**

But I'm writing a dynamic Angular2 component that needs to be able to access the path to that file and update its template dynamically. So I need to be able to somehow get **img.3423543534234325346436.png** in the code, not the HTML template.

For example, in an Angular2 component:

```
private myIcon = 'img.png';
```

And then in the template:

```
<img [src]='myIcon' />
```

How can I get the hashed filename inside the Angular2 code?

Comment: try it with define plugin `new Webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.Hash': [hash] })`, if this does not work then in your index.html assign it to var [hash]